# Is $T(x,y)=(xy,0)$ a linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

Need to show that:
$T = {R}^2 \rightarrow {R}^2 $  is not a linear transformation

$T([ x,  y]^ {T}) = [xy, 0]^ {T}   =  T  $

Can you help get started.

Comment: For it to be a linear transformation, it needs to satisfy certain axioms. Try to prove that (at least) one  of them fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For linearity we need $f(\alpha (x,y)^T) = \alpha f((x,y)^T)$ where $\alpha(x,y)^T = (\alpha x, \alpha y)^T$.

But in this case we have
$$T(\alpha(x,y)^T) = (\alpha x \cdot\alpha y,0)^T = \alpha^2 (xy,0)^T = \alpha^2 T((x,y)^T)\neq \alpha T((x,y)^T)$$
therefore $T$ is *not* linear.

Answer (score -1):

$[0,0]=T([x,0])+T([0,y])=T([x,y])$ and $T([x,y])$ is different from zero in general.